# Disable XSD validation against http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd in Websphere AS

Tags: java, websphere

I'm deploying a .war in Webshepere AS 6.1 with this in `web.xml`:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
```

But it errors with

> This site is experiencing technical difficulty. We are aware of the issue and are working as quick as possible to correct the issue.

How can I avoid this? How can I disable validation against an external XSD in Websphere AS?

Comment: Finally similiar to this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519785/failed-to-read-schema-document-http-java-sun-com-xml-ns-persistence-persistenc i put in local server jsp_2_1.xsd, , javaee_web_services_client_1_2.xsd, web-app_2_5.xsd, javaee_5.xsd and fake /etc/hosts and work...

Comment: This sounds like a product issue.  XML documents should be validated against XSD files included with the product.  I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM.  Out of curiousity, what is the stack trace of the failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere AS 6.1 is a [J2EE 1.4 platform](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rovr_specs.html); that means Servlet 2.4. The server does not support the application version being installed.

The correct declaration would be something like:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
>
```

You need WebSphere AS 7 for Java EE 5 and Servlet 2.5 support.

Comment: Yeah, thanks... but the problem is the same... java.sun.com is dowm! :)